# Is there any way to register a notification when ip address changed on device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ip

I want to use NSStream to send send and receive information to server.
I thought if I can obtain the ip address the server can send information back in order to replace the silent push notification.

Is is possible to register a notification when ip address changed?

P.S.
I'm currently using reachability class to register a notification when network changed but if there is a better way it'll be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not straight way to achieve this but Use

```
`[[NSHost currentHost] address];`
```

save value into userDefault and every time when you connect check with stored value and get notify

i found this on SO hope this work for you

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

- (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

                }

            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;

}
```

Comment: Not available for iOS, I already checked. It sends me to NSStream and give an error (No known class..., Receiver 'NSHost' for class message...).